# Android Scoped Storage and External Storage

Tags: android, react-native, mediastore, android-contentresolver, android-download-manager

I have an app that wants to have the ability to download files locally. A user can download a file (no restrictions to file type) and should be able to save it on the device so it can be used for other purposes. I would also like the user to be able to delete the file from the app (they would know which file is downloaded and which isn't, a ticker would indicate if it's backed up locally). Say it is a pdf file -- the user would want to open it with different apps or edit it if they have the ability to, or just share it via email. Considering we cannot opt out of scoped storage anymore (requirement to target 30), I got a couple of questions.

I've tried to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath())` and also `getExternalFilesDirPath(ctx, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))`. While the former is deprecated, it works for me in that the Files app can be used to navigate to the file in question (and possibly open/delete the file). On the other hand, I am not being able to delete this file from my app due to lack of permissions. Obviously, the latter path is unable to be navigated to by another app (or is it? I haven't found a way, hence the question).

The other thing I've considered using is the MediaStore API but I'm struggling to see how this is an improvement over the old ways in terms of function. Disregarding moving back to manual content resolver and cursor usage, how should arbitrary files be sorted? Should I manually sort by mime types and have different methods for saving for specific media types? It sounds exceptionally tedious and counter intuitive. If this is the way, so be it, I will implement it, but it does not sound like the way to go. On the positive side, it at least sounds like a solution due to the content resolver's CRUD abilities.

I'm working on a RN app that uses a 3rd party library for the download paths, which old/new versions, respectively, use different paths (rn fetch blob and rn fetch blob util). Additionally, MediaStore API doesn't have a RN implementation as of right now, so everything would have to be done from scratch, too.

What are my options? In the short term I'm considering disabling the erase feature from the app (at least for now). Anything I am missing and should consider? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your app can download to the Download directory, hence create a file there,  it can also delete that file. Please elaborate.

Comment: @blackapps I don't think that is the case. Upon trying to delete the file downloaded to the `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath())` path (I can check if it exists and I do before erasing) I get an error -- `EUNSPECIFIED`. This https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/236 is the link I've found most similar to my problem (despite I don't get a success), but folders don't seem to matter. Besides, it doesn't make sense to save all files in a non-downloads folder anyway, no?

Comment: Who is saving files in a non-downloads folder? And what does it have to do with your problem? I repeat: `If your app can download to the Download directory, hence create a file there, it can also delete that file`. You did not elaborate.

Comment: What do you want me to elaborate more than the deletion fails? The error is as cryptic as it can get. I assumed what you're saying is true, as well, but it is not, hence the stackoverflow question. And to answer the only question you're asking -- my app uses a 3rd party lib that saves the data in the Downloads folder. The same library from the same app tries to delete it unsuccessfully despite the file's existence in the specified place (I triple check it every time via the Device File Explroer). The same library can also check the file's existence correctly.